# Balanceamento de parênteses, como checar se estão na posição correta?

Tags: java

Estou fazendo um programa que recebe uma string e verifica se parênteses abertos estão fechados.
Tenho o seguinte código:

```
int abertos = 0, fechados = 0; //conta os parenteses
    parens = parens.replaceAll("[^()]", "");//fiz essa linha considerando que a entrada contenha caracteres que não sejam parenteses
    for (int i = 0; i < parens.length(); i++){
        if (parens.charAt(i) == '(')
            abertos++;
        if (parens.charAt(i) == ')')
            fechados++;
        return abertos == fechados ? true : false;
    }
```

Se a entrada for " () " ou " )(" ele retorna true, porém todos concordam que " )( " não são parênteses fechados, logo preciso de um script para resolver essa situação. Mas, qual? Fiquei umas 2 horas quebrando a cabeça e não achei a resposta, peço a ajuda dos leitores!

Comment: Você pode usar uma pilha, e cada vez que for fechar um parenteses ele vai tirar um dessa pilha, se o que tirar não corresponder, significa que fechou errado

Comment: Muito obrigado Natan, sou iniciante e ainda não conhecia a classe Stack, me ajudou muito!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como indicado nos [comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/500393/balanceamento-de-par%C3%AAnteses-como-checar-se-est%C3%A3o-na-posi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-correta#comment926339_500393) você pode usar uma pilha para testar o balanceamento de parênteses de uma sentença.

O mecanismo é simples, receba uma string como entrada e itere por seus caracteres, toda vez que:

- encontrar um parênteses de abertura, `(`, empilhe-o.
- encontrar um parênteses de fechamento, `)`, verifique:

  - se a pilha estiver vazia é porque a entrada está desbalanceada.
  - se o topo da pilha contiver um parênteses de abertura, `(`, desempilhe-o.
- encontrar um caractere deferente de um parênteses de abertura, `(`, ou um parênteses de fechamento, `)` ignore-o.

Após iterar pelos caracteres da entrada:

- se a pilha estiver vazia é porque a entrada está balanceada.
- se restar elementos na pilha é porque a entrada está desbalanceada.

Exemplo:

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.*;

class Main {  
  
  static Stack<Character> pilha = new Stack<Character>();
  
  public static void main(String args[]) {         
    String s = System.console().readLine(">>>");     //Lê uma linha.
    //Itera por cada caractere da sentença s...
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
      char c = s.charAt(i);     
      //...verifica se o caractere é (...
      if (c == '(') {
        pilha.push(c);                              //...empilhe o caractere.
      //...verifica se o caractere é )...
      } else if (c == ')') {
        //...verifica se a pilha estiver vazia...
        if (pilha.empty()){
          System.out.println("Desbalanceado");      //...expressão desbalanceada.
          return;                                   //...encerra a função.
        }
        pilha.pop();                                //...remove o que estiver no topo da pilha.
      }
    }
    //Verifica se após a iteração a pilha não estiver vazia...
    if (!pilha.empty()){
      System.out.println("Desbalanceado");          //...expressão desbalanceada.
      return;                                       //...encerra a função.
    }    
    System.out.println("Balanceado");               //a expressão está balanceada.
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma possibilidade de script para o seu cenário

```
    int abertos = 0; 
    parens = parens.replaceAll("[^()]", "");
    if(parens.length() % 2 != 0) return false; //Caso não seja um valor par também será falso e não precisa entra no loop
    
    for (int i = 0; i < parens.length(); i++){
            if (abertos == 0 && parens.charAt(i) == ')') return false; //caso não tenha nenhum parentes aberto e seja um fechado já retorna false
            if (parens.charAt(i) == '(') abertos++;
            if (parens.charAt(i) == ')') abertos--;
        }
    return abertos == 0; //Caso a quantidade parentes não seja igual a zero, então também está errado
```